# Conditionally color output from Oracle lsdg asmcmd

Tags: bash, oracle

I'm stuck and was wondering if this is even possible.

I would like to display the result of `asmcmd`'s `lsdg` but would like to give it a red background if the data or index values are under 20gb.

This is what I have so far:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/asmcmd lsdg>>$DAILY
echo>>$DAILY
```

where `$DAILY` is the path of the daily checklist file.

I have no idea how to display is so that those with values of `Usable_file_MB` under 20GB will be highlighted.

So far I've achieved this through PL/SQL, maybe I can display this in a text file with a red background?

```
SET heading OFF
select (case when usable_file_mb < 40000 then 'echo -e "\033[41m' else 'echo -e "\033[40m' end)|| name||' '|| state||' '|| total_mb||' '|| usable_file_mb || '\033[m"' from v$asm_diskgroup
```

Comment: You could use `grep -E --color` with a pattern matching sizes of less than 20gb (that would be red text though rather than red background). What's the format of `asmcmd lsdg`'s output? Does it provide a unitless output which would make the pattern simpler?

Comment: The output is as follows:
ASM DISK SPACE
State    Type    Rebal  Sector  Block       AU  Total_MB  Free_MB  Req_mir_free_MB  Usable_file_MB  Offline_disks  Voting_files  Name

MOUNTED  EXTERN  N         512   4096  1048576    737088    38055                0           38055              0             N  DB_DATA/


I'm trying to see if there is a way to get individual columns, so far I've only achieved through PL/SQL

Comment: @Lilz please add the output to your post.